# MySQL InnoDB add new instance to existing cluster

Tags: mysql, innodb

`Server version: 5.7.23-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

I'm running an InnoDB cluster and trying to add a new node, the cluster is a couple of years old and binlogs are being cleared after 2 weeks.

Adding a new node to a new cluster is straight forward enough because the master has all the binlogs but I can't find anywhere pointing me to instructions on how to add a new node to an existing cluster.

It's in production and I don't want to 'test and see' in case I break something so I'm looking for a definitive set of instructions.

Can anyone assist please?

Comment: i would use [xtrabackup from percona](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup) to create a non-blocking db replica. then restore that and use the bin log position that is saved when creating the backup. super straight forward. sorry on my phone. hard to edit and get the links. [here’s one](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.3/howtos/setting_up_replication.html)that i quickly found and i used in the past

Comment: Cheers Raul, I was hoping I didn't have to install any extra software, I'll check it out though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The old way of adding a Slave might be best:

1. Stop mysqld on an existing Slave (Replica)
2. Copy the disk (or at least *all* of MySQL's stuff)
3. Change the server_id
4. See if something in the Master contains a list of servers in the topology; if so, augment it
5. Start mysqld on both replicas.